# Hash function from string using MAD

Tags: hash

The MAD (multiply-add-divide) method computes hash as follows for some value `x`,
`h(x) = ((ax + b) mod p) mod N`
where `p` is a prime number larger than `N`, `a` and `b` are some random integers in the range [1, p-1] and `N` is the size of the hash table.

How do I compute the hash of a string value?
I'm not sure if I should compute the hash of the string (such as based on place value) and then use the MAD method or is there another way?

What I've tried?
I want to implement a function `int hash(str)` which will return the hash value.
I have written `int hash(int x, int N)`, but here I'm sending a pre-calculated `x` based on ASCII value of characters in string.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two sensible ways to do this.

1. Treat each character as its own number (many programming languages have the `ord` function) and chain the evaluations of `h` is such a way that for example you use the value for `a` or `b` as the result of the previous result of `h`.
2. Treat the whole string as a single number. You can convert a string to a bytes array which can be converted through some kind of big integer library into a single number. This can be used as input for `h` which must then be implemented with the same big integer library as well.

There is no telling which of those two methods are faster. I would guess it is the first one, but both of them don't guarantee any properties similar to a cryptographic hash function. There are many more ways to do this.